# Highlight arbitrary rectangular regions

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, color

Is it possible to highlight specific and arbitrary rectangles in a buffer? I want to implement a code scope highlight that groups code into a hierarchy of boxes. here is my mockup that I made:

[image]

assuming that the coordinates of the boxes are computed for the buffer contents using a standalone script (to liberate it from any dependency on the syntax system and language semantics), I wonder how practical it could be to render the background colors inside vim to an arbitrary degree (many areas going beyond the end of lines need to be painted).

Comment: while you can highlight lines, it is impossible to highlight arbitrary rectangular regions, unless the width is smaller than the smallest line it covers.

Comment: That's what i feared @ChristianBrabandt :(

Comment: On a side note, I think using folding would be much easier to read and much more comfortable than this kind of highlighting [`:h folding`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#folding)

Comment: I would rather scroll farther than to make content invisible. But yes I have looked at folding before.